# Width: Auto Taking the First Element's Width

Tags: css, width

Have a div and there's a small link div inside that's 630 pixels wide and other little larger table inside that's 697 (According to the Firebug Layout inspector).

The containing div has width: auto and the layout inspector tells me that it's getting 630 for it's width. Why is this happening? Why isn't it picking the larger of the two values?

Comment: What is the (div and the table)'s display and position set to?

Comment: Can you post simple example code here or on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using position: relative; on all the corresponding divs?

Comment: I am not using either. I do not have direct control on what may go inside this <div>

Comment: Do you have access to the css?

Comment: I do not have access to the CSS. It's content I have no control over.

Comment: what do you have access to change?

Comment: @bobber: How can you have no access to CSS if you can see the page in the browser? You said you have firebug - so you can change html/css whatever you want

Comment: I can't have access to the content because I don't know what it'll be. I can't rely on being able to change the CSS, even if it wasn't a maintenance nightmare to do so.